# Convert list haskell

Tags: list, haskell, integer

I have this list ([Integer],[Integer])
which I want to convert into [(Integer,Integer)].

From what I've read I should use high order functions like map.

```
alterList :: ([Integer],[Integer]) -> [(Integer,Integer)]
alterList a = map(\a -> .....?)
```

Any guidelines? Both lists are of the same size.

Like I have two lists ([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,9]) which I want to convert to [(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)]

Comment: It is not entirely clear how you will map `[([Integer], [Integer])]` to `[(Integer, Integer)]`. The 2-tuple can contain two lists with different size... So concatenating is not a straightforward conversion.

Comment: There are lots of ways to implement a function with this type signature. You're going to have to provide some sample inputs with the intended output for each. (This isn't like, for example, `fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` that only has one possible implementation that obeys the functor laws.)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `alterList = fmap (bimap f f)`, where `f` is some function of type `[Integer] -> Integer`. `bimap` (from `Data.Bifunctor`) would apply `f` to each list in a tuple, and `fmap` would apply `bimap f f` to each tuple in the output list.

Comment: Assuming you want `[(1,3),(2,4),(4,6),(4,7),(5,8)]` when the input is `[([1,2],[3,4]), ([4,4,5],[6,7,8])]` then the function you're looking for is `alterList = concatMap (\(l1,l2) -> zip l1 l2)`. But well, we cannot guess what you want, as said in the above comments.

Comment: I have two list like [([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])] and want it like [(1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8)]

Comment: `[([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])] ` is *one* list. It contains the unique element `([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])`, which is a pair of two lists. The brackets (`[]`) are useless if you only have a pair of two lists. Not clear yet...

Comment: Ouf, my bad, those outher brackets should not be there, ([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]) is more correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after you've corrected your post, I think you want

```
alterList :: ([Integer],[Integer]) -> [(Integer,Integer)]
alterList (l1, l2) = zip l1 l2
```

Example:

```
>>> alterList ([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,9])
[(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,9)]
```

This is equivalent to

```
alterList' :: ([Integer],[Integer]) -> [(Integer,Integer)]
alterList' = uncurry zip
```

Note that this function works even if the two lists have not the same size: in this case it acts as if the longest list were truncated to the length of the shortest one.